# Unable to insert into user defined type in Cassandra

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

I have user defined type and the table in Cassandra as :

```
CREATE TYPE message (
  txt text,
  pub_date text
);


CREATE TABLE user_messages(
    username text,
    messages list<frozen <message>>,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
```

I am trying to insert the data in the table through the Python code as:

```
session.execute('''update user_messages set messages = {txt :'''+ '"'+request.json.get('text') +'"'+''',pub_date:'''+ str(int(time.time())) +'''} where username=''' + username)
```

But it is not working correctly for the input of txt field as : "This is my new tweet".
The console output for error is :

```
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:64 no viable alternative at input ',' (...set messages = {txt :["This is my new twee]t",...)">
```

If I make the input txt field as simpler one like : "tweet" then the error is

```
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:49 no viable alternative at input ',' (...set messages = {txt :["twee]t",...)">
```

Am I missing anything? 
Is there any other way to insert the data into user defined data type?
I tried using INSERT query as well but it failed. So I tried using UPDATE command. Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax error due to the fact that you use double quote ("this is my tweet") for the value of message->txt. Make sure that you insert with single quote, something like:

```
{txt: 'This is my tweet', pub_date: 'yesterday'}
```

Comment: txt field is obtained from the request JSON object and its being passed in double quotes.

Comment: Seems like you are inserting the double quote with `+ '"'+`

Comment: Is there any way to load the data into the user defined type for the table I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, you need to fix the syntax error. You are inserting `{txt: "This is my tweet",...` and you need to insert:  `{txt: 'This is my tweet',...`

Comment: I modified the statement like                                   
 session.execute('''update user_messages set messages = {txt :'''+ "'"+request.json.get('text') +"'"+''',pub_date:'''+ "'"+str(int(time.time()))+"'" +'''} where username=''' + "'" + username  +"'") and now the error is                                                
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid user type literal for messages of type list<frozen<message>>"

Comment: You still need the bracket for the list: `[ .... ]` Essentially, this query will work `INSERT INTO user_messages (username , messages ) VALUES ( 'bob', [{txt: 'hello', pub_date: 'today'}]) ;`

Comment: This way is working if I execute the query on the cassandra command prompt. But I want to use it through Python code and making this query as parametrized one.

Comment: I understand. This was just an example on CQL to indicate that you are missing the brackets `[...]` for the list on your previous attempt